# combining the data in longitudinal study

Tags: panel-data

In longitudinal studies, there are two longitudinal projects with the same measurements.

Study A: (Wave 1) 2015 -> (Wave 2) 2019 (4-year longitudinal)
Study B: (Wave 1) 2018 -> (Wave 2) 2023 (5-year longitudinal)

When combining these two studies, concerns arise due to the different measurement points (Study A: 2015 vs. Study B: 2018) and durations (Study A: 4 years, Study B: 5 years).

Would conducting an ANOVA for Studies A and B to verify they come from the same population distribution and treating the durations (4, 5) as covariates solve the issue?
Is there a better approach?